# Modify java script in GTM to include product subtotal

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I've trying to figure this one out since my dev is not able to pass subtotal value by product.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

I added this script in GTM java script variable in order to create a product array based on data layer. But I need to add **product subtotal** , which should pass value of **productPrice * productQuantity .**

```
function()
{

var productName = {{dlv - productName}};
var productId = {{dlv - productId}};
var productPrice = {{dlv - productPrice}};
var productBrand = {{dlv - productBrand}};
var productCategory = {{dlv - productCategory}};
var productVariant = {{dlv - productVariantTitle}};
var productQty = {{dlv - productQuantity}};
var productSku = {{dlv - productSku}};
var productSubtotal = ;
var items = [];

for( i = 0; i < productId.length; i++ ){
    items.push(     
        {
          'item_name': productName[i],
          'item_id': productId[i],
          'item_brand': productBrand[i],
          'item_category': productCategory[i],
          'item_variant': productVariant[i],
          'price': productPrice[i],
          'quantity': productQty[i],
          'sku': productSku[i],  
          'subtotal': productSubtotal[i],
        }
    );
}
return items;
}
```

I tried few options but either get total product value (all products summed up instead of itemised), or no value at all.

In this case, i tried adding a new GTM variable to pass the total amount, but i need totals by product.

```
function(){
  var productList={{DL - Checkout - Products}};
  var totalAmount=0;
  for(var i=0;i<productList.length;i++)
  {
    totalAmount+=(productList[i].quantity)*(parseFloat(productList[i].price));
  }
  return totalAmount;
}
```

Comment: Please add your debugging attempts. Through the GTM preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already know the concept. But didn't put it together

```
function(){
    var productName = {{dlv - productName}};
    var productId = {{dlv - productId}};
    var productPrice = {{dlv - productPrice}};
    var productBrand = {{dlv - productBrand}};
    var productCategory = {{dlv - productCategory}};
    var productVariant = {{dlv - productVariantTitle}};
    var productQty = {{dlv - productQuantity}};
    var productSku = {{dlv - productSku}};
    var productSubtotal = 0;
    var items = [];

    for( i = 0; i < productId.length; i++ ){
        productSubtotal = productQty[i] * parseFloat(productPrice[i]);
        items.push({
              'item_name': productName[i],
              'item_id': productId[i],
              'item_brand': productBrand[i],
              'item_category': productCategory[i],
              'item_variant': productVariant[i],
              'price': productPrice[i],
              'quantity': productQty[i],
              'sku': productSku[i],  
              'subtotal': productSubtotal,
        });
    }
    return items;
}
```

Just make the subtotal in the for loop and before the items.push